# R: uploading large tables to SQL Server

Tags: r, sql-server

I am working with the R programming language.

I have a large data frame (`my_df`) stored on my computer than I am trying to upload to a (Netezza) SQL Server. This data frame is 5 columns and 10 million rows.

Currently, I am using the following code to do this:

```
library(odbc)
library(DBI)

con <- dbConnect(odbc :: odbc(), dsn = "abc", encoding = "latin1")

dbWriteTable(con, SQL("my_df"), my_df)
```

This code has been running for a long time and still has not yet finished running.

**My question:** are there some alternate (faster) approaches in R that I can use to upload this table to the server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is using the `dbWriteTable()` function with the chunk_size argument. This argument allows you to specify the number of rows to insert into the database at a time. This can be useful for improving performance, especially with large data frames.

To use the chunk_size argument, simply add it to the `dbWriteTable()` function call, like so:

```
dbWriteTable(con, SQL("my_df"), my_df, chunk_size = 10000)
```

This will insert the data frame into the database in batches of 10000 rows. You can adjust the chunk_size argument to find a value that works best for your data and hardware.

Another approach:

```
dbWriteTable(con, SQL("my_df"), my_df, insert_method = "BULK")
```

The `BULK` method is a more efficient way to insert large amounts of data into a database. It uses a bulk insert statement to insert the data in a single batch.